# How to program resize widget like Qt Creator (Not using QSizeGrip)

Tags: c++, qt

In **Qt Creator** we can resize widget by moving mouse cursor to **blue square point** (mouse cursor will change to arrow shape) then we will press left mouse and pull to change size of widget.

[image]

I created a widget and i want to implement that resize idea for it. How can i do it ? Thanks

Comment: Please show us a bit of code, like have you tried doing anything just yet?

Comment: @TheRealNox: My old code is using QSizeGrip to resize widget, this idea is new and i still thinking how to do it and i need some instructions to start with so i haven't written code yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so there might be some already implemented solution out there, but that how I would go with:

- Overload those three functions of the parent widget:

  ```
  void    mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
  void    mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
  void    mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
  ```
- Keep track of the initial blue square postition inside the MousePressEvent(...).
- Inside MouseMoveEvent(...) find out the difference between the actual mouse position and the initial one. (Be sure that the user is still clicking ;) ).
- Use the previously found delta and resize the widget accordingly.
- Remember to set a bool or something when the user release the mouse button using the mouseReleaseEvent(...).

Using those steps, you should have a good prototype running.

Comment: Thank you, i have those ideas in mind too. Can i ask you another thing is how can we draw 8 blue points like that ?

Comment: There is a tons of way. I would recommend this reading from the Qt website [Basic Drawing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html).